# In SharePoint 2013 onPrem, default Permissions

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions

I'm doing a little project for a my company that has recently installed SharePoint 2013.

The problem I'm having is that all domain users can Read the sites I built even though they have not been entered as Members in any SharePoint site Permission group. When I Check Permissions for such a user, it shows:
*Permission levels given to John Doe -- None.*
It then goes on with:
*The following factors also affect the level of access for John Doe*
And lists *Allow* for a dozen items.

I see in the Central Admin's **Policy for Web Application** there is a **User Policy** for **Everyone** with **Full Read**, but if I set this to **No Access**, no one (not even I) can access the sites at all.

How do I configure SharePoint so the default for users not specifically entered in a Permission group is *No Access*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the User Policy for "Everyone".  If there is one, it supersedes what you do on the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the WebApplication setting called "User Policy" in SharePoint Central-Administration -> Application Management -> Manage Web Applications -> Select your WebApplication -> User Policy.